Modeling the replacement of a conveyor belt
Im new to blender and im trying to animate the replacement of a conveyor belt, the model has the new rolled belt (which i modeled creating a spiral curve, then transforming it into a mesh and then applying solidify), and a group of rollers (cylinders), so the tip of the rolled belt pass through the rollers following a curve.

I tried using cloth simulation and collisions (internal and to the rollers), pinning the center of the rolled belt and assigning a hook to the tip of the rolled belt, then making keyframes to move the tip through the rollers, but the belt looked wrinkled and the movement looked unstable and fell of to the sides.
I also tried creating a spiral curve and a curve that follows the path through the rollers and joining them to apply a curve modifier to a plane with the dimensions of the belt, but the belt only follows the path of the spiral, and then it completely ignores the rollers curve.

Im open to any idea, i will like it to look as high quality and realistic as possible but im absolutely new to blender and animation. Any suggestions? What am i doing wrong?


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Ok I unloaded it, sorry if its a mess, any tutorials on general good practices are also welcomed. Thanks!

Worth looking for 'rolling carpet' tutorials which you might be able to modify for your use. There are several on YT.
